# Jquery load problem -- for one person only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page on my website that was visited 96 times. Only 1 page visit generated the javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" which I understand means that the jquery library didn't load properly. What I don't understand is:
(a) How could this problem happen to this person when it didn't to anyone else.
(b) What can I add to my code to detect the problem and handle it. Note that I store the useragent of each visit and the visitor in question had the same useragent as many other page visits that did not have the problem.

NOTE: The last several questions I posted on this website were rejected for various reasons, so if this happen to this question, I'd be super grateful if someone could  please give me specific instructions as to what I can do to make this question accepted.

EDIT: My question was closed. I was told to include: (a) desired behavior. (b) a specific problem or error. (c) the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

1. I thought my program does include a specific problem or error: a visitor getting the javascript error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".
2. I thought the desired behavior would be avoiding this problem.
3. As far as reproducing the problem, I wouldn't know how to do that because only 1 visitor out of 96 got the error. I could post the link to the page but most people will not get the error.

Also, I am reluctant to post the actual link of the page because it is  not a page of the website which is open to the public -- it is a private link that only members have access to, and posting the link would expose members' info, which I am reluctant to do.

Finally, I have received some comments and replies that actually seem to answer my question. So it feels confusing that I have asked a question and received good replies that I am considering attempting, and at the same time having the question downvoted multiple times and closed.

I'd be really grateful if someone could help clarify my confusion, and add a comment with specific suggestions as to how I could have posted my question in a way that would have been accepted.

Comment: Request to your jQuery library may fail (various reasons) and there will be no jQuery loaded, but code execution continues. Usually if you can't reproduce it, than assume it's some temporal issue that can't be fixed and is not worth looking into.

Comment: If you load from CDN, perhaps that person had a network error right when it was loading jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading jQuery from an external server bundle it with your Javascript. That way either all of your JS will load (and include jquery) or none of it will load if there is an error while requesting the file.